# Use Arelle to export XLSX file

Tags: python, finance, xbrl, edgar, arelle

I'm trying to use [Arelle](http://arelle.org/documentation/command-line-operation/) to export a XLSX file from a zip of XBRL files. It works just fine when I use the [EdgarRenderer](http://arelle.org/documentation/edgar-renderer-installation/edgar-renderer-technical-operation/) plugin.

> ./arelleCmdLine -f data/goog-20151231.xml.zip --plugins EdgarRenderer
>   --disclosureSystem efm-pragmatic --validate -r /home/out/

This produces a Financial_Report.xlsx file which is what I want. I'm trying to do this without generating the additional HTML files. I found the plugin [saveLoadableExcel](http://arelle.org/documentation/command-line-operation/) but I'm not sure how the commandline arguments work. I tried the following -

> ./arelleCmdLine -f data/goog-20151231.xml.zip  --plugins
>   saveLoadableExcel.py --save-loadable-excel --validate -r /home/out/

But I get the following error -

> [info] Activation of plug-in Save Loadable Excel successful, version
>   0.9. - saveLoadableExcel.py  [info] loaded in 6.58 secs at 2017-12-15T12:43:09 -
>   /home/data/goog-20151231.xml.zip/goog-20151231.xml  [info] validated
>   in 9.68 secs - /home/data/goog-20151231.xml.zip/goog-20151231.xml 
>   [exception:saveLoadableExcel] File saving exception: 'bool' object has
>   no attribute 'write' - goog-20151231.xml  Exception ignored in: > Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1595,
>   in **del**   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1608, in close
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1711, in _write_end_record 
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 680, in write
>   AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'write'

How can I export just the excel file? Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to export to .xlsx? If so please share the command. I am facing a similar issue as you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `store_true` on the [option](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/blob/f19224ca83b8a488383eec15284cb63f0219c323/arelle/plugin/saveLoadableExcel.py#L437). This will store `True` in the `saveLoadableExcel` option which will be read by:

```py
excelFile = getattr(options, "saveLoadableExcel", None)
```

You can copy this plugin and fix it in your project by removing the `action="store_true",` line and use that, or create a MR for Arelle.

Then you can create the excel by passing the destination like this `--save-loadable-excel file.xlsx`